# How to prevent users from clicking multiple times on a linked image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I have a page with a linked image, where the link takes a bit of time to load. Therefore, users tend to click multiple times on it. This occasionally causes errors to crop up in the code. How do I prevent users from clicking on the link more than once?

In an attempt to remedy this, I changed the link to an onClick event and then in the function I used the code:

```
$('#myImageId').unbind('click');
window.location.href = "myLink";
```

However, that doesn't seem to be helping. Also, I'd prefer to keep it a simple linked image instead of using javascript.

Comment: you're going to have to choose javascript or letting your users satisfy their ocd tendencies. what does your html look like?

Comment: I guess I'll choose javascript then...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once solution is to add a class to the element that is used as a flag to determine of the code should run.

**Here's an example:** http://jsfiddle.net/qLhr8/

```
$('#myImageId').click(function() {
   var $th = $(this);
   if( !$th.hasClass( "pending" ) ) {
           // Add the "pending" class, so subsequent clicks will not
           //   run the code inside this if()
       $th.addClass( "pending" );
       window.location.href = "myLink";
       // you could do a setTimeout to remove the class
       //   if the new page never loads
   }
});
```

With the added class, you can also change the look of the image (lower its opacity perhaps) to indicate that it shouldn't be clicked again.

```
.pending {
    opacity: .4;
    filter:alpha(opacity:40);
    cursor: wait;
}
```

Comment: Simple and elegant with a good user experience by letting them know that something's happening. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="..." id="myImageId">


$('#myImageId').bind('click', function() {
    $(this).unbind('click');   
    /* do long time task....
});
```

if your image is wrapped by a link the code will be

```
<a href="#"><img src="..." id="myImageId"></a>


$('#myImageId').parent().bind('click', function(evt) {
    $(this).unbind('click');   
    /* do long time task....

    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A hacky CSS solution that might/might not work: create another image element, without the link and make it a sibling to the link, like this:

```
<div>
  <a href="http://www.long-loading.com" id="link"><img src="my_img.png" id="img_link" alt="GO" /></a>
  <img src="my_img.png" id="img_nolink" alt="GO" />
</div>
```

Now apply this CSS:

```
#img_nolink { display: none; position: relative; top: -200px; /* Height of the image */ }

#link:active + #img_nolink { display: block; }
```

This should show the non-link image when the link is clicked (theoretically).