# Prevent users from repeatedly clicking on links

Tags: php, javascript, database, performance

When you click a given link, it loads a page that makes a stored procedure call.  If the stored procedure call takes more than a few seconds, people start clicking the link again.  If they click the link a dozen times, I can see a dozen queries run on the database.  The last query is the only one that returns anything to the user, but the other 11 execute to completion while using resources.

What is the best way to prevent this?  Is there a way to stop it at the database level or is this an interface issue?  Is this a result of how I am making my database connections with PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent users from clicking multiple times on a linked image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892354/how-to-prevent-users-from-clicking-multiple-times-on-a-linked-image)

Comment: The solution may end up being a duplicate of that, but I'm hoping to find an alternate solution.  If I could address this in the database or server side (PHP) I would prefer that solution to disabling elements with javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I would tackle the interface issue - the reason behind users clicking multiple times is not that the users are wrong, but rather that your site isn't communicating anything about what it's trying to do. Consider setting the link to disabled onclick, perhaps displaying some kind of loading animation, and then re-enabling the link once you get the callback with the data. That way the UI reflects the back-end state at all times, and also prevents users queuing up a bunch of requests!

Comment: A problem with disableling a link when clicking is, for instance, when connection drops. If the callback is not received, the link cannot be clicked again (a legitimate reason to click twice) and perhaps any data in forms is lost if the user has to refresh. In this case: use a timeout to re-enable the link.

Comment: Very good suggestion - the last thing you want is to leave the UI disabled because of a dependency on something which cannot be guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to disable the link for the duration of the query. You could do this with some local JavaScript that updates the current page or switch to another page that doesn't have the link on it at all - it all depends on your site design.

Another alternative would be to set up a guard variable in the code so that it only calls the stored procedure when it's unset:

```
if (!callingProcedure)
{
    callingProcedure = true;
    call procedure
}
```

Then when the procedure returns reset `callingProcedure` to false.

Having some sort of progress indicator will also help - giving your users feedback that the site is actually doing something.

Answer (score 1):

use something like the [jQuery BlockUI Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#page) to block the page while the request is processed. This gives your users the certainty that something is happening and prevents them from clicking again.